# AJAX in chat applications

Tags: node.js, ajax, chat

When I read about how to create chat applications in Node.js, I found out that the recommended way to do so was to use Socket.io and websockets.

I also read that we can regularly send requests using AJAX and wait for responses from the server.

So my question is: Can AJAX serve the same purpose as WebSockets, and use AJAX for chat applications instead of WebSockets?

Comment: You can but it would be inefficient to do so.

Comment: Of course you can, but it would be really inefficient. Why exactly you can't use http protocol to push data from the server?

Comment: I mean that we can't send data from the server unless the client send a request

Comment: But why will it be inefficient?

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events server events to notify your clients about new events.

Comment: websocket is a protocol running over http (it actually open a full duplex http channel where server and client can communicate at any time in both direction, client -> server | server -> client). It's oftenly use in chat cause it look faster for the user and it's easier for the develloper to manage event like "a new user joined/leave the room". Ajax still can do the jobs thought, it's up to you to choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *have* to use websockets for chat applications, there is actually a wide range of technologies you can use.

**AJAX:** AJAX, or long polling can be used for web chats, but is considered a primitive and inefficient way to get updated chat information. The client listens for a change on the server-side, then when it get's a response from the server, it then makes another request to listen for requests. The reason this is looked down upon is because they client could be listening for a long time, without a response from the server.

**WebSockets:** Websockets is a protocol that runs over HTTP that facilitates bi-directional data. Similar to the TCP websocket protocol, there is a 3-way handshake involved in order to make a connection. [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) aids in the use of websockets by abstracting a lot of the raw websocket functions. The truth is that Socket.io actually provides backwards compatibility with browsers that only support long-polling or Flash for chat communication. Unlike WebRTC, there is a man-in-the-middle (server) to facilitate who is chatting with who.

**[WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/):** WebRTC is a free, open project that provides browsers and mobile applications with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple APIs. These protocols allow peer-to-peer communications (chat included) with little use of a middle-man, or server. To address your question, it's great for "private-chats".

**Flash:** It is possible to use Flash for chat communications over the web. This is severely outdated, as Flash is slowly dying from the web.